# How to retrieve pending and executing Celery tasks with their arguments?

Tags: python, celery

In Celery docs, there is the [example](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#dump-of-currently-executing-tasks) of inspecting executing tasks:

> You can get a list of active tasks using active():
>
> ```
> >>> i.active()
> [{'worker1.example.com':
>     [{'name': 'tasks.sleeptask',
>       'id': '32666e9b-809c-41fa-8e93-5ae0c80afbbf',
>       'args': '(8,)',
>       'kwargs': '{}'}]}]
> ```

But this call returns only representations of arguments, obtained by `repr()`. Is there way to get serialized tasks arguments?

Comment: `eval()` on the value of `args` will return a tuple

Answer (score 7):

OK, I'm gonna drop this in as an answer. Hope this addresses your concern.

Celery offers up a string for the args. To handle it, and get a list:

```
args = '(5,6,7,8)' # from celery status

as_list = list(eval(args))
```

Of course, `eval()` is a little dangerous, so you may want to use literal eval:

```
import ast

args = '(5,6,7,8)' # from celery status

as_list = list(ast.literal_eval(args))
```

That's how I handle parsing Celery args in my workflows. It's kind of a pain.

Answer (score 5):

How willing to hack on the core Celery code are you? The representation returned via .active() ultimately comes through this code: https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/b1deab39aad2fdec95f48b9f6e19ca1967285544/celery/utils/saferepr.py#L68

And is set on the request here:
https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/master/celery/worker/request.py#L120

You could modify those functions to return whatever representation of objects you desired... of course doing so might break something else.

Also, @economy had a good comment about possibly eval'ing the repr. All depends on what your main goal is.